# Pass data from UITableView to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get a JSON response and display data in my viewcontroller.

I have this JSON response:

```
{"status":1,"data":{"blocks":[{"name":"CustomBlock","description":"CustomDescription","items":[1]}], "items":[{"id:"1", name: "testgame"}]}
```

I have blocks with name, description, and array of items. Also, all items is passing here with the key "items"

I have created this tableview class

**BlocksTableView.swift**

```
class BlocksTableView : UITableView, UITableViewDataSource, 
UITableViewDelegate
{
    var blocks = [Block]()
    var items : BlockItem!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
        self.loadBlocks()
    }
    func loadBlocks()
    {
        guard let url = URL(string : "myURL") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse.self, from: data)
                self.blocks = response.data.blocks;
                self.items = response.data.items;

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.reloadData()
                }
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print(jsonErr)
            }
            }.resume()
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return blocks.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BlockCell") as? BlockCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        cell.blockName.text = blocks[indexPath.row].name
        cell.blockDescription.text = blocks[indexPath.row].description
        cell.gameCollectionView.reloadData()
        return cell
    }
}
```

Now I want to display items in collectionview inside tableviewcell, but I have no idea how to do this. Since each block has different count of items, I need to pass blocks and items variables to my CollectionViewClass, right? But how to do this properly?

Here is my collectionviewclass

```
class GameCollectionView : UICollectionView, 
UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate
{
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //here i need to return number of items in current block, something like blocks[0].items.count
        return 0
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "GameCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as? GameCollectionCell else { return
            UICollectionViewCell()
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Actually, your solution is wrong. If each BlockCell has a collectionView, as I understood, your GameCollectionView class is useless. Each row needs to have a collectionView (in your prototype row you can add it), then your BlocksTableView must be the CollectionViewDelegate and DataSource, and provide elements for each collection view in each row.
An answer implementing this solution is just be added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
class BlocksTableView : UITableView, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var blocks = [Block]()
    var items : BlockItem!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
        self.loadBlocks()
    }
    func loadBlocks()
    {
        guard let url = URL(string : "myURL") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse.self, from: data)
                self.blocks = response.data.blocks;
                self.items = response.data.items;

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.reloadData()
                }
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print(jsonErr)
            }
            }.resume()
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return blocks.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BlockCell") as? BlockCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        cell.blockName.text = blocks[indexPath.row].name
        cell.blockDescription.text = blocks[indexPath.row].description
        cell.gameCollectionView.delegate = self
        cell.gameCollectionView.dataSource = self
        cell.gameCollectionView.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.gameCollectionView.reloadData()
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return  blocks[collectionView.tag].items.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "GameCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as? GameCollectionCell else { return
            UICollectionViewCell() } 

      // here use  blocks[collectionView.tag].items[indexPath.row] for each item
        return cell
    }
}
```